# Cancel an APK download/install

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm currently using

```
ret.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
ret.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkLocation), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

to download and install an APK from the internet within an AsyncTask's doInBackground method. I also have a progress dialog with a cancel button. Upon pressing the cancel button, the APK should be deleted. How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[Call `delete()` to delete a `File`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29).

This may or may not stop the installation, and you have no control over that, as it is the OS, not you, that is installing the APK.